# What are the applications/advantages of using partially applied functions in scala?

Tags: scala, partial-application

We have partially applied functions in Scala-

```
def sum(a:Int,b:Int,c:Int) = a+b+c

val partial1 = sum(1,_:Int,8)
```

I was wondering what are the advantages of using Partially applied functions. Or is it just a syntactical addition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About partially applied function in general, the book "[Programming in Scala, 2nd edition](http://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_2ed)" mentions:

> Another way to think about this kind of expression, in which an underscore
>   is used to represent an entire parameter list, is as **a way to transform a
>   def into a function value**.
>   For example, if you have a local function, such as `sum(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int): Int`, you can “wrap” it in a function value whose apply method has the same parameter list and result types.

```
scala> def sum(a: Int, b: Int, c: Int) = a + b + c
sum: (a: Int,b: Int,c: Int)Int
scala> val a = sum _
a: (Int, Int, Int) => Int = <function3>
```

(Here, `a(1, 2, 3)` is a short form for:

```
scala> a.apply(1, 2, 3)
res12: Int = 6
```

)

> **Although you can’t assign a method or nested function to a variable, or pass it as an argument to another function, you can do these things if you wrap the method or nested function in a function value by placing an underscore after its name.**

Comment: Yeah, so I see that we can create a function value and pass around as just any other variables. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

The advantage is that `sum(1,_,8)` is less to type and read than `x => sum(1,x,8)`.

That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 1):

> sum(1,_,8) is less to type and read than x => sum(1,x,8)

However, neither is legal; you must provide the parameter type.